# multivariable calculus, existence of partials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be a continuous funciton on $I=(a,b)\times (c,d)$ such that

(i) $f_x$ exists and continuous on $I$.

(ii) For some $x_0\in (a,b)$, $f'(x_0,y)$ exist.

(iii) $f_{xy}(x,y)$ exist and continuous on $I$.

Show that $f_y$, $f_{xy}$ exists and $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$.

I dont know how to approach this. Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: I would start by writing the partial derivatives as limits of difference quotients.